# Why is that the "size" attribute in a "<input>" tag in HTML only applies to TEXT and not NUMBER?

Tags: html, css

If I have a HTML file with the tag `<input type="text" size="3" …>`it does what it should do, it renders an input element with the width of 3 characters. On the other hand, if I have the tag `<input type="number" size="3" …>` it renders the default width for an input field (much longer than 3 chartacters).

I know I can make a custom class with a `.myclass { width: 75px; }`, but I think it would be much easier to use the size attribute, specially if I know for a number field that the numbers accepted will be from 0 to 100, why to use a wider input field?

Is this done by design? Am I required to use CSS for this? If that so, how can I render an input field of exactly three characters wide according to the font family/size I'm using in the form?

Comment: Try min='1' max='100' maxlength='3' and add a class then restrict the width with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5">
```

Is this what you are looking for? Other then that, I haven't found anything that would resize the input. I think the best thing to do is use css in your css file or add style="" to the input field.

Comment: He also wants the size to be limited to 3. I've already answered it with the correct syntax.

Comment: And if you read correctly, he also said that size="3" is NOT working.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested the following:

```
<input type="number" size="20" min="1" max="5"/>
```

The `size` attribute didn't respond on `Chrome` or `FireFox`, but very surprisingly it did work on `Internet Explorer 11`.

My guess is it's still in the process of receiving global compatibility, and I would recommend creating a css class to handle the width as you so desire.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqsuqckb/2/) of the code for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Size is not an attribute for input type=number, it has min and max attribute to specify minimum and maximum number. To adjust width you will have to use width style.

Comment: True. Oddly enough, Chrome seems to render the `size` attribute on `input=number` correctly, but Firefox doesn't. In general, it's better to control sizes of elements with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me.

```
<input type="number" size="3" max=1 min=5>
```

Edit. Need to add min and max for size to work.

Comment: Not working for me, even if I change max and min for proper values.